# Cant access varnish without www

Tags: redirect, varnish, service

Yesterday i installed varnish and memcached on my CentOS 6 32-bit VPS server for my magento store, when i go to www.my-website.com or http://my-website.com it works, but when i type in firefox "my-website.com" i have

```
    Error 503 Service Unavailable

    Service Unavailable

    Guru Meditation:    
    XID: 1512050071
```

I tried to redirect, but no efect

```
if (req.url ~ "http://my-website.com") {
      error 750 "http://www." + req.http.host + "my-website\.com";
 }

if (req.url ~ "^my-website.com") {
      error 750 "http://www." + req.http.host + "my-website\.com";
 }
```

///////////

Ok, I found solution.
I replaced localhost with my server ip in backend default.vcl

Comment: Users can delete their own questions; 
Simply click the delete link underneath the question.

Comment: Or you can answer your own question; it may be useful to others.